Selected Option Not Displayed in Dropdown Placeholder After Fetching Data
I'm working on a project where I'm fetching data from a database using a Laravel API. The data is used to populate a dynamic dropdown list. When I select an option from the dropdown, the correct data is returned based on the selected option, but the selected option is not displayed in the dropdown's placeholder bar after selection.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Listbox, ListboxButton, ListboxOption, ListboxOptions } from "@headlessui/react";
import { CheckIcon, ChevronDownIcon } from "@heroicons/react/20/solid";
import { HiOutlineUserGroup } from "react-icons/hi2";

export default function SelectCategory({ onChange ,value}) {
  const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null); // Initially no category selected

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tourCategory")
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data || [];
        setCategoryData(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching category:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleCategoryChange = (category) => {
    console.log("Selected Category:", category); // Debugging line
    setSelectedCategory(category.category);
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(category.category); // Pass the entire category object or adjust as needed
    } else {
      console.error("onChange function is not defined");
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <Listbox value={selectedCategory} onChange={handleCategoryChange}>
      <div className="relative">
        <ListboxButton className="relative w-full h-[5vw] border-x-[0.1vw] cursor-default text-center text-gray-900 hover:ring-1 hover:ring-inset hover:ring-gray-300 focus:outline-none ">
          <span className="mx-[0.5vw] border-b-[0.1vw] flex justify-between">
            <div className="mr-[0.7vw]">
              <HiOutlineUserGroup className="text-black h-[1.7vw] w-[1.7vw]" />
            </div>
            <label className="font-semibold mr-[0.7vw] text-[1.5vw]">Category</label>
            <div>
              <ChevronDownIcon
                aria-hidden="true"
                className="h-[2vw] w-[2vw] text-gray-800"
              />
            </div>
          </span>
          <span>
            <span className="ml-[1vw] text-sm text-gray-500 block truncate">
              {selectedCategory ? selectedCategory.category : "Select a category"}
            </span>
          </span>
        </ListboxButton>

        <ListboxOptions className="absolute z-10 mt-1 max-h-[20vw] w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
          {categoryData.length > 0 ? (
            categoryData.map((category, index) => (
              <ListboxOption
                key={index}
                value={category}
                className="group relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-gray-900 hover:bg-[#247D7E] hover:text-white"
              >
                <div className="flex items-center">
                  <span className="block truncate font-normal group-data-[selected]:font-semibold">
                    {category.category}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <span className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4 text-[#247D7E] group-data-[focus]:text-white [.group:not([data-selected])_&]:hidden">
                  <CheckIcon aria-hidden="true" className="h-5 w-5" />
                </span>
              </ListboxOption>
            ))
          ) : (
            <p className="py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-gray-900">
              No categories available.
            </p>
          )}
        </ListboxOptions>
      </div>
    </Listbox>
  );
}



The dropdown correctly fetches and displays the options.
After selecting an option, the expected data is returned, but the selected option is not shown in the dropdown’s placeholder he allways show "select category" text.


Hello do you have some options when you are logging it ?

no i don't have



import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Listbox, ListboxButton, ListboxOption, ListboxOptions } from "@headlessui/react";
import { CheckIcon, ChevronDownIcon } from "@heroicons/react/20/solid";
import { HiOutlineUserGroup } from "react-icons/hi2";

function SelectCategory({ onChange, value }) {
  const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null); // Initially no category selected

  useEffect(() => {
    setCategoryData([
      {
        category: "Category1",
        id: 1
      },
      {
        category: "Category2",
        id: 2
      }
    ]);
  }, []);

  const handleCategoryChange = (category) => {
    console.log("Selected Category:", category); // Debugging line
    setSelectedCategory(category);
  };

  return (
    <Listbox value={selectedCategory} onChange={handleCategoryChange}>
      <ListboxButton className="relative w-full h-[5vw] border-x-[0.1vw] cursor-default text-center text-gray-900 hover:ring-1 hover:ring-inset hover:ring-gray-300 focus:outline-none">
        <span className="mx-[0.5vw] border-b-[0.1vw] flex justify-between">
          <div className="mr-[0.7vw]">
            <HiOutlineUserGroup className="text-black h-[1.7vw] w-[1.7vw]" />
          </div>
          <label className="font-semibold mr-[0.7vw] text-[1.5vw]">Category</label>
          <div>
            <ChevronDownIcon aria-hidden="true" className="h-[2vw] w-[2vw] text-gray-800" />
          </div>
        </span>
        <span>
          <span className="ml-[1vw] text-sm text-gray-500 block truncate">
            {selectedCategory ? selectedCategory.category : "Select a category"}
          </span>
        </span>
      </ListboxButton>

      <ListboxOptions anchor="bottom">
        {categoryData.map((category) => (
          <ListboxOption key={category.id} value={category} className="data-[focus]:bg-blue-100">
            {category.category}
          </ListboxOption>
        ))}
      </ListboxOptions>
    </Listbox>
  );
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



This code is kind of working for me can you please check once!!

yes when i give data from a list like you he work correctly  but when i give him from my api he  work  but don't show the selected option in the placeholder

As far as I can understand code, API only fetches and fills up categories available. So post that this array should look same as api response. Can you please check API response once, if category name field is category and not label or value or something else.
